# Building BDC Model using Custom Connector

Tags: sharepoint-2013, bdc

I'm building a BDC Model on Sharepoint Foundation 2013, and would like to use the custom connector.

Does anyone have a tutorial? even better if it can show some good practices..?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look on my personal blog:
http://jmecwel.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/sp13-search-index-sql-products

I'm showing an example on how to index Products from a SQL server using a custom BDC on SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Hi jmecwel, do you know in the executeStatic method, if SP provides the current logged in user? Thanks again!!

Comment: I don't know if you can retrieve the current user in the BDC connector execution, did you try SPContext, or HttpContext?